# To capture message from a character after specific texts

Tags: r

I have a following character in R. Is there way to populate only text coming after [SQ].

Input

```
df   # df is a character
[1] "[Mi][OD][SQ]Nice message1."                        
[2] "[Mi][OD][SQ]Nice message2."                         
[3] "[RO] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'SELECT * FROM "
```

Expected output

```
df
[1] Nice message1. Nice message2
```

In case there are more [SQ] like below

```
df   # df is a character
[1] "[Mi][OD][SQ]Nice message1."                        
[2] "[Mi][OD][SQ]Nice message2."                         
[3] "[RO] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'SELECT * FROM "
[4] "[Mi][OD][SQ]Nice message3."
```

Expected output

```
df
[1] Nice message1. Nice message2. Nice message3
```

Comment: single string with all 3 messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to use `str_extract` to extract the substring and then wrap with `na.omit` to remove the `NA` elements which occur when there is no match for a string.  Here, we use a regex lookaround to check the pattern `[SQ]` that precedes other characters to extract those characters that are succeeding it

```
library(stringr)
as.vector(na.omit( str_extract(df, "(?<=\\[SQ\\]).*")))
#[1] "Nice message1" "Nice message2" "Nice message3"
```

If it needs to be a single string, then `str_c` to collapse the strings

```
str_c(na.omit( str_extract(df,  "(?<=\\[SQ\\]).*")), collapse = '. ')
#[1] "Nice message1. Nice message2. Nice message3"
```

#### data

```
df <- c("[Mi][OD][SQ]Nice message1.", "[Mi][OD][SQ]Nice message2.", 
"[RO] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'SELECT * FROM ", "[Mi][OD][SQ]Nice message3."
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the time. But actually. it wont be Nice message.  I just gave  sample. Basically what ever is next to [SQ]  it should extracted

Comment: but I am getting ````[1] "Nice message1." "Nice message2." "Nice message3."
attr(,"na.action")
[1] 3
attr(,"class")
[1] "omit"

Comment: Like attr, omit and all

Comment: @imranp It is just the attributes.  You can wrap with `as.vector(` and would be gone.  Or use `is.na`